# A few problems with Typescript/tslint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to Typescript! Just trying to do basic annotation as a start

First, one of the imports keeps yelling
Second, `type` is not picked up inside object destructuring
Third, jsx is not working correctly it seems.

My code

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useMappedState } from "redux-react-hook";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";

type TodosReducer = {
    todos: []
}
const mapState = ({ todosReducer: TodosReducer }) => ({
  todoCount: todosReducer.todos.length,
  todos: todosReducer.todos
});

export default function TodoList(): HTMLDivElement {
  const { todoCount, todos } = useMappedState(mapState);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>You have {todoCount} todos</div>
      <ul>
        {
            todos.map((todo: string, index: number) => <li key={index} {...todo}>,/li.)
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ok. Line 2 `redux-react-hook` keeps yelling, cannot find a package. 'react' was doing the same on line 1 unless I ran yarn install in this branch again.

Then I'm not able to line mapState tslint keeps saying

`[ts] 'TodosReducer' is declared but its value is never read.
[ts] Binding element 'TodosReducer' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

So basically I do have type defined above it for TodosReducer but still.

Last, inside the TodoList function returning `<div>...</div>` tslint keeps saying `cannot find name div` for all the elements

> cat tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                       
    "module": "es6",                     
    "allowJs": true,                     
    "jsx": "react",                     
    "sourceMap": true,                     
    "outDir": "./dist",                       

    "strict": true,                        
    "noImplicitAny": true,                

    "moduleResolution": "node"

  }
}
```

Comment: Why a -1? care to explain?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're trying to address many problems at once. If you're new to TS, consider sorting them out one by one.

Comment: Would you find it optimal to repeat same 15 lines of code for three separate questions?

Comment: You don't need 15 lines for all of them. All you need is https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you have problems importing React, that's 1 line. It's very likely that all of the problems were previously answered on SO, so you will be linked to duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third-party packages need to have typings in TypeScript. `@types/react` should be installed together with `react`, etc.

```
const mapState = ({ todosReducer: TodosReducer }) => ({ ... })
```

is incorrect syntax to type `todosReducer` parameter. It's treated as ES6 destructuring syntax. The correct one is:

```
...
type TodosState = { todosReducer: TodosReducer };

const mapState = ({ todosReducer }: TodosState) => ({ ... );
```

`useMappedState` is generic function, it's supposed to be used as:

```
useMappedState<TodosState>(mapState);
```

Comment: I have types for React. So does it mean I need to have types for `redux-react-hook` package  as well?

Comment: Oh yeah! So how do I go about the todosReducer annotation ? Do annotation on all of object? State in my case. For example, `const mapState = (state: StateType) => ({})`

Comment: Where StateType will be `type StateType = { todosReducer : { todos: []} }`. Seems overkilling it. Any better way?

Comment: I just updated it. Yes, there should be something like StateType . You will use it several times.

Comment: As for redux-react-hook., it was written in TS and already contains typings (.d.ts file). You can check package contents in node_modules. Make sure you use latest version. I mentioned `react` because of *'react' was doing the same on line 1*

Comment: Oh! I mentioned that I made it go away by doing `yarn install` later in question description.

Comment: For redux-react-hook I have the latest version as  `"redux-react-hook": "^3.0.0", `

Comment: Try to delete the whole node_modules and reinstall packages. If the problem persists, make sure that  `node_modules/redux-react-hook` directory really exists.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` and `yarn install`. Same error. Pretty sure it exists in node_modules.

Comment: The question does not show how exactly you compile the project and where it's 'yelling'.

Comment: Ha-ha.  Where ? `tslint` yelling at line 2 as mentioned. What do you need to know about compile?  Using vscode and tslint plugin by egamma to compile I guess.

Comment: Small update. Changed the file from .ts to .tsx and that resolves my last error - `cannot find name div` So only one is left:)

Comment: Regarding tsx, this makes sense, sorry, I forgot to address this. *tslint yelling at line 2 as mentioned* - you didn't provide actual error messages but I don't think it's TSlint, it isn't its responsibility to check modules, I guess it's TS compiler. Consider compiling the project apart from VScode, i.e. from command line. This could be an issue with VScode rather than anything else. At this point too many things are involved, and nobody but you can replicate the problem.

Comment: Yeah. True. Can be tooling.   So I ran `tsc /path/to/TodoList.tsx`.  And I actually got 4 errors ( redundant ) with all saying cannot `Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.`  'react' package took a little time to resolve too but it did. So shall I assume that redux-react-hook is safe?

Comment: Looking into the flag issue. Don't worry about that.

Comment: If `react` module is resolved without errors, I'd expect that `redux-react-hook` should be resolved too and not cause an error. I'd expect tooling problems. If you want `tsc` to use tsconfig.json, you shouldn't use arguments, otherwise the config is ignored. It's either one or another.

Comment: So basically runnin tsc on fileName would obviously fetch jsx errors because it doesn't have access to tsconfig.json file.  So that's sorted and is not an actual error

Comment: Cool! Almost typed the same thing. Have opened the issue on repo - https://github.com/facebookincubator/redux-react-hook/issues/11 in case.  See it helped a beginner in TS and not necessarily a beginner in React ecosystem. Thanks for help.